# OData POST $batch requests

Tags: http, odata, batch-processing

I'm working on an OData API Integration.
This is my first time working with $batch and I'm having some trouble building my payload.  I have the following, but it's only returning a payload: `--batchresponse_51006caa-b23c-43a6-9a67-edf6a4351368--`  And it is not updating the record.

Here is the payload I'm attempting to POST, with only 1 record

```
{
      "requests": [
                {
          "id": "r1",
          "method": "PATCH",
          "url": "https://host/data/entity(dataAreaId='ent',InvoiceNumber='0533561',InvoiceDate=2023-11-22T12:00:00Z)",
          "headers": {
            "content-type": "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; odata.streaming=true",
            "odata-version": "4.0"
          },
          "body":
            {"TranProcessed": "Yes"}
        }
      ]
    }
```